# Normal Regex works but RegExp Object Doesn't

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regex to match any object and the simplest I could think of is `/./g`. I tested this using javascript by two possible methods(one with [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and another using normal syntax).

For some reason, the regex doesn't work as expected while using the [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Please check the below code snippet and help me to understand why [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) returns false for **0** and **5**.

```js
var regex=new RegExp(".","g");
var objectsArray=["Hello","$234",0, 23, 234,"Text",5];
for(object of objectsArray){
  console.log("Current Value : " + object);
  console.log("Normal Regex  Result : " + /./g.test(object));
  console.log("RegExp Object Result : " + regex.test(object))
}
```

Comment: As you can see, if you add `regex.lastIndex = 0` before logging, the values will appear as expected.

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer - Thanks for the link, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work for only 0 and 5. Why don't we need to reset the lastIndex for other values?

Comment: Because the cursor is further than its length.

Comment: @Salketer - Let me reorder the elements and confirm.

Comment: @Salketer - Yes, you are right. Am happy to mark this as duplicate.